# All backends within Matplotlib fail and give me a TypeError:'figure' is an unkown keyword argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, backend, figure

I haven been running a script to create subplots for a while, now the script which has been unchanged has a TypeError: 'figure' is an unknown keyword argument. Originally I never used a backend, but because of this error I have tried all that I could find and none of them fix the problem.
My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "Qt4Agg"  # e.g.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cluster = 1
title = 'TimeSeries_Plot_Spring_' + str(cluster) 
A_data = pd.read_csv('TimeSeries/Spring_TimeSeries_DaAn_ERA_1979-  2012_vF.csv', index_col = 1)
p_data = pd.read_csv('TimeSeries/prob_Spring_TimeSeries_DaAn_ERA_1979-2012_vF.csv', index_col = 1)

place = 1
k = 10 #number of clusters

for i in range (1,k+1):
    A = A_data.loc[place] #select one row of data per time
    p = p_data.loc[place]

    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()   
    plt.title('Time Series Daily Anomalies Spring: Cluster ' + str(cluster))
    plt.hlines(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=2012, linestyle = '--', zorder=10 )
    ax2 = ax1.twinx() #reproduce a second y-axis for the probability data

    p.plot(kind = 'bar', label = 'percent of days', ax=ax2, color = 'lightgrey', align = 'center')
    ax2.set_ylim([0, 60])
    ax2.set_ylabel('days (%)', color = 'black')

    ax2.set_zorder(1)   

    A.plot( label = 'Flooded Area (km2)', ax = ax1)
    ax1.set_ylim([-40, 30])
    ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel = 'Flooded Area (km2)', color = 'blue')
    ax1.set_zorder(2)
    ax1.set_axis_bgcolor('None') #otherwise the bars disappear

    fig.canvas.draw()

    visible_labels = [lab for lab in ax1.get_xticklabels() if lab.get_visible() is True and lab.get_text() != '']
    plt.setp(visible_labels[1::2], visible=False) 

    for tick in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        tick.set_fontsize('small')
        tick.set_rotation(65) #otherwise the years cannot be read

    plt.tight_layout()    
    place += 1
    title = 'TimeSeries_Plot_Spring_' + str(cluster)
    cluster += 1
    plt.savefig('Cluster_Plots/' + title + '.png')

plt.show()
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-b55e1369fcaa> in <module>()
 35
 36     #plt.figure(figsize=(10,7.5))
---> 37     fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
 38     plt.title('Time Series Daily Anomalies Spring: Cluster ' + str(cluster))
 39     plt.hlines(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=2012, linestyle = '--', zorder=10 )

/p/system/packages/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex, sharey, squeeze, subplot_kw, gridspec_kw, **fig_kw)
1175         gridspec_kw = {}
1176
-> 1177     fig = figure(**fig_kw)
1178     gs = GridSpec(nrows, ncols, **gridspec_kw)
1179

/p/system/packages/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in figure(num, figsize, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, frameon, FigureClass, **kwargs)
525                                         frameon=frameon,
526                                         FigureClass=FigureClass,
--> 527                                         **kwargs)
528
529         if figLabel:

/p/system/packages/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.pyc in new_figure_manager(num, *args, **kwargs)
 41     FigureClass = kwargs.pop('FigureClass', Figure)
 42     thisFig = FigureClass(*args, **kwargs)
---> 43     return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, thisFig)
 44
 45

/p/system/packages/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.pyc in new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
 48     Create a new figure manager instance for the given figure.
 49     """
---> 50     canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)
 51     return FigureManagerQT(canvas, num)
 52

/p/system/packages/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.pyc in __init__(self, figure)
214         if DEBUG:
215             print('FigureCanvasQtAgg: ', figure)
--> 216         super(FigureCanvasQTAgg, self).__init__(figure=figure)
217         self._drawRect = None
218         self.blitbox = None

/p/system/packages/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.pyc in __init__(self, figure)
 63
 64     def __init__(self, figure):
---> 65         super(FigureCanvasQTAggBase, self).__init__(figure=figure)
 66         self._agg_draw_pending = False
 67

/p/system/packages/anaconda/2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.pyc in __init__(self, figure)
237         # The need for this change is documented here
238         #    http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#cooperative-multi-inheritance
--> 239         super(FigureCanvasQT, self).__init__(figure=figure)
240         self.figure = figure
241         self.setMouseTracking(True)

TypeError: 'figure' is an unknown keyword argument
```

Can anybody please help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: What's happening is that matplotlib tries to use the Qt5 backend, and fails, because you probably don't have PyQt5 installed (I assume this, since PyQt5 is not straightforward to get to work in python 2.7). Just to make sure: you do get the exact same error (triggered in *backend_qt5.pyc*), when using `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` as the second line in your script? Have you recently installed or upgraded any python related packages or programs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have used this code on a python version that has PyQt5 installed. But I have found that when I altered the backend and run the script again in the same Ipython consule, the backend doesn't change.  Running the code with the following backend: matplotlib.use('Agg') in a seperate python console fixed the problem for me